# Show another number when calling mobile phone

Tags: mobile, android, iphone, spoofing

Nowadays I heard that some cheaters make mobile calls to steal banking & other private information.They show private numbers like 911 to their victims.

Is it possible show different number to victim when calling another mobile phone.?

Is it possible by using a program or by any other means?

Comment: yes this is possible, you can search google for companies that provide phone number masking services. There might be legal restrictions depending on what country you attempt to do this in!

Comment: dgn - you'll see that all your questions so far have been closed or are duplicates of existing questions. I would suggest re-reading the [about] page for guidance on how to ask questions, and also using the search function before asking a question.

Comment: I looked possible duplicate question.He asked for other employee's phone number.But I asked for private number for governments like 911,155,110 .In my opinion questions different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how it can be effectively done by directly calling the phone line (such as using phone masking services offered by companies), but I can think of a way of doing that using the data line (wi-fi/3g etc) first and then starting the call.

---

Attacker creates a program which pretends doing something useful, however it also has an activity/screen which exactly imitates the phone call activity/screen. After installed in the OS, program starts a service which tries to communicate (using 3g or wi-fi) with the server of the attacker when needed. When they want to communicate, phone call imitator activity is started and user is deceived with a number like 911. User thinks he/she is answering the call, however in fact he/she is the one who is calling the attackers phone which is obviously not 911.